# NodeJS stops listening on port 443

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are having a big problem with nodejs intermittently not listening on port 443. Development claims that this is because node cannot connect to the Mongo database. However, when I get an alert the port is not listening, I can still see there are hundreds (973 at this time) of connections to the Mongo servers from /usr/bin/node.

When Mongo support is asked about this they claim there is no evidence of connections being dropped expect for normal fin handshakes and an occasional reset.

So the sides are pointing fingers at each other and Systems is stuck in the middle.

Nodes:  version 12.22.1

OS:  CentOS 7.8.2003 (Yes, I know it is not fully up to date)

If there is any other information you might need, just ask. If someone has a  suggestion as to where I can find logs that might help clear this up, please tell me where.

Comment: ` I can still see there are hundreds (973 at this time) of connections to the Mongo servers from /usr/bin/node.` Perhaps it is affecting new connections or was a short duration event that didn't affect existing connections. Is the database local?

Comment: It is not what I would call short duration.  The loss of listening on 443 usually lasts a minute or less but there are a few events that lasted about ten minutes.

The database is not local.  It is managed by MongoDB and their servers are somewhere in Azure.